# Fetching the Bit version of an .exe file using csharp

Tags: c#

I am trying to determine whether an .exe file present is of 64 bit or  of 32 bit . I am trying to achieve this through CSharp. I have few solutions like sigcheck and exe64bitdetector  which are command line tools which will get the desired output. Is there anyway this can be achieved through CSharp.

Comment: @DanWilson I agree, if the asker is only looking at .NET executables. There may be some additional work for handling Win32 executables.

Comment: @Dan I am trying to get bit version of an external .exe file .

Comment: What is an `external .exe file`?

Comment: Use a library to parse the Windows PE header.

Comment: @DanWilson. I mean it need not be be a .net assembly. It could be any .exe file .

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892097/parsing-plain-win32-pe-file-exe-dll-in-net. See https://github.com/secana/PeNet